# Share data between unrelated components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the scenarios. I have a `Graph` component that appears in the body of the page, where the user can make some changes.

I also have a `Search` component that appears in the header of the page.

The two are unrelated - `Graph` only appears in the body of this one page, while `Search` appears in the header of all pages. They belong to `app.js`, which is currently just this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('search', require('./components/Search').default);
Vue.component('graph', require('./components/Graph').default);
/* other components */

import PerfectScrollbar from 'vue2-perfect-scrollbar'
import 'vue2-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue2-perfect-scrollbar.css'

Vue.use(PerfectScrollbar);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data : {



    },

    methods : {



    },

    mounted : function(){



    },

    computed : {



    }
});
```

Now, when the user changes the data in `Graph`, I am supposed to send that change to `Search`. It doesn't really matter what the data is, I just need to figure out the sending process.

So, how do I send something from `Graph` to `Search`? I've been trying to emit the change, but I have no idea how to capture it in `Search`. I've used emit before with child/parent components, but I can't find documentation on how to do it here.

Logically, I think it should go through `app.js` somehow, but I can't find the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases you generally have two options.

The preferred method is to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), which gives your application a global state, which can be shared across your entire application.
Making it easy to share data between components that have no direct relation.

The other option is to use an Event Bus, which gives you a way to listen and send events across your component. But this approach isn't considered best practice and should be avoided if possible.

If you want *do* want to go with an event bus, Vue recommends using [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt).

Comment: Thanks. If I'm reading the Vuex docs correctly, I can mutate the `state` in the `store` from my `Graph` component. But does that mean that I would need to store the data there instead of the `Search` component? Or can I emit from the `store` to `Search` after every mutation?

Comment: You're going to store the data in the Vuex store (state). Your `Search` component will then retrieve the data from the store. And because of Vue's reactivity, whenever you update the state from your `Graph` component, it will automatically be updated in the `Search` component

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a `centralized store` or a State and [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is your answer.

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications.
> It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an
> application